# Error: Could not find or load main class com.b.pokebot.PokeBot while using Java Maven

Tags: java, maven

I'm not an advanced Java programmer, but I want to create a Discord messenger bot. In order to do that, I need to add additional dependencies to my application. I chose Maven instead of Gradle.
For now, I try to run a basic program:

```
package com.b.pokebot;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.AccountType;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.Message;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.MessageChannel;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.User;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.exceptions.RateLimitedException;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class PokeBot extends ListenerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent e) {

        //Obtains properties of the received message
        Message objMsg = e.getMessage();
        MessageChannel objChannel = e.getChannel();
        User objUser = e.getAuthor();

        //Responds to any user who says "hello"
        if (objMsg.getContent().equals("hello")) {
            objChannel.sendMessage("Hello, " + objUser.getAsMention() +"!").queue();
        }

    }
}
```

I added maven-jar-plugin to my pom.xml under the  tag:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.b.pokebot.PokeBot</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Tried to add addClassPath to  as well.

For now, I cannot run the program with command

```
java -jar target/pokebot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

because of error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.b.pokebot.PokeBot
```

Even though there is a class in that package...
If I remove the maven-jar-plugin entry, I get a similar error, but instead of class name, I get my jar file name.

Could someone tell me how to fix that, so I can run the program from command line?
When I run it from Netbeans, there is no problem...

btw: I altered package name - the "b" is a longer word in the actual code.

Comment: You must ensure that you add the location of your .class file to your classpath. So, if its in the current folder then add . to your classpath. Note that the os classpath separator is a semi-colon.

Comment: Where should I do that? For pom file, I see only a <addClassPath> node...

Comment: Is `java com.b.pokebot.PokeBot` working?

Comment: `Error: Could not find or load main class com.b.pokebot.PokeBot` - of course used with the proper package name - still has problems...

Comment: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

A helpful link https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-manifest-file-with-maven/

Comment: So, without packaging to a jar, you can not run the Main class, right?

Comment: I cannot run even with packaging - except that I can run it in Netbeans. But in Netbeans I have set the main class manually.
Also, I don't have `meta-inf/manifest.mf` file.